# Float 2 images on same row using a CSS stylesheet (background-image property)

Tags: css, image, background-image

I have 2 images which are the exact same height and width. I want them to sit on the same row. However, combined they are much larger than the body width. I've inserted them through the HTML tags using IMG tags.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/image-background.jpg" alt="">
      <p>Test image 1 off google.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/image-background.jpg" alt="">
      <p>Test image 2 off google.</p>
    </li>
 </ul>  
</div>
```

To restrain there size, I floated them left and applied a % width.
Here is the CSS for the code:

```
.wrapper{
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

#gallery{
  list-style:none;
}

#gallery li{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

Instead of the IMG tag, can I use `background-image:url('')` to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: use divs instead of img, see here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did that worked.

```
#gallery li{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
//I added this and removed the original img tags in the html code. 
  background-image:url(http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/image-background.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height:500px;
}
```